# Tabbing inside (nested) itemize environment using tabto

Tags: itemize, tabto, column-width

I'm writing a two columns document using the package `multicol`. In a two levels list, I would like to tab some text to the center of the column. Since I use this tab a lot, I previously defined the following command

```
\newcommand{\ta}{\tabto{0.5\columnwidth}}
```

Now, I would expect `\columnwidth` to remain the width of the entire column (in the same way as `\textwidth` should remain the width of the body). Instead, if I have nested, the tabbed text will end up at different positions.

[image: result with unaligned tabbed text]

This is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,table,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize[landscape]{A4}

\setmarginsrb{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{2cm}{5pt}{2pt}{5pt}{23pt}
\newcommand{\ta}{\tabto{0.5\columnwidth}}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\ta The real center

\begin{itemize}
    \item First level: \ta text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item second level:\ta unaligned
    \end{itemize}
    \item Equation:\ta $a^2=b^2+c^2$
\end{itemize}


\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

The same behaviour is observable in one-column documents using `\textwidth`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you look into the documentation of tabto? The first sentence already says "Tab to a position relative to the left margin in a paragraph (*any indentation due to a list is part of the `margin' in this context*)."

Comment: Shame on me. I looked into the documentation of multicol (without finding the solution) before discovering that the same behaviour could be observed in one-column documents and then embarassingly enough I didn't think at a possible explanation in tabto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer for pointing out my negligence.

To have some text tabbed to mid-column, one just have to subtract the `\leftmargin` parameter of the current item.

Here a shorter version without using the `multicol` environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\tabto{0.5\textwidth} The real center

\begin{itemize}
    \item First level: \tabto{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - \the\leftmargini} text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item second level:\tabto{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - \the\leftmargini - \the\leftmarginii} 
              aligned
    \end{itemize}
    \item Equation:\tabto{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - \the\leftmargini} 
          $a^2=b^2+c^2$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]